# How to maintain database integrity when table inheritance cannot be used

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I have several different component types that each have drastically different data specs to store so each component type needs its own table, but they all share some common columns. I'm most concerned with [component.ID] which must be a unique identifier to a component regardless of component type (unique across many tables).

**First Option**

My first idea was inheritance where the table for each component type inherits a generic [component] table.

```sql
create table if not exists component (
    ID long primary key default nextval('component_id_seq'),
    typeID long not null references componentType (ID),
    manufacturerID long not null references manufacturer (ID),
    retailPrice numeric check (retailPrice >= 0.0),
    purchasePrice numeric check (purchasePrice >= 0.0),
    manufacturerPartNum varchar(255) not null,
    isLegacy boolean default false,

    check (retailPrice >= purchasePrice)
);

create table if not exists motherboard (
    foo long,
    bar long
) inherits component; //<-- this guy right here!!

 /* there would be many other tables with different specific types of components 
which each inherit the [component] table*/
```

PostgreSQL inheritance has some caveats that seem to make this a bad idea.

1. Constraints like `unique` or `primary key` are not respected by the inheriting table. Even if you specify `unique` in the inheriting table it would only be unique in that table and could duplicate values in the parent table or other inheriting tables.
2. References do not carry over from the parent table. So the references for `typeID` or `manufacturerID` would not apply to the inheriting table.
3. References **to** the parent table would not include data in the inheriting tables. This is the worst deal breaker for me using inheritance because I need to be able to reference to all components regardless of type.

**Second Option**

If I don't use inheritance and just use the `component` table as a master component list with data common to any component of any type and then have a table for each type of component where each entry refers to a `component.ID`. that works fine but how do I enforce it?

**How do I enforce that each entry in the `component` table has one and only one corresponding entry in only one of many other tables?** The part that baffles me is that there are many tables and the corresponding entry could be in any of them.

A simple reference back to the `component` table will ensure that each row in the many specific component type tables has one valid `component.id` to which it belongs.

**Third Option**

Last of all I could forego a master component table altogether and just have each table for a specific component type have those same columns. Then I am left with the conundrum of how to enforce a unique component ID across many tables and also how to search across all these many tables (which may very well grow or shrink) in queries. I don't want a huge unwieldy UNION between all these tables. That would bog any select query to frozen molasses speed.

**Fourth Option**

This strikes me as a problem that comes up from time to time is DB design and there is probably a name for it that I don't know and perhaps a solution that is different entirely from the above three options.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key should contain the type of a subcomponent, the example speaks for itself.

```
create table component(
    id int generated always as identity primary key, 
    -- or
    -- id serial primary key, 
    type_id int not null,
    general_info text,
    unique (type_id, id)
);

create table subcomponent_1 (
    id int primary key, 
    type_id int generated always as (1) stored,
    -- or
    -- type_id int default 1 check(type_id = 1),
    specific_info text,
    foreign key(type_id, id) references component(type_id, id) 
);

insert into component (type_id, general_info) 
values (1, 'component type 1');

insert into subcomponent_1 (id, specific_info) 
values (1, 'specific info');
```

Note:

```
update component
set type_id = 2
where id = 1;

ERROR:  update or delete on table "component" violates foreign key constraint "subcomponent_1_type_id_id_fkey" on table "subcomponent_1"
DETAIL:  Key (type_id, id)=(1, 1) is still referenced from table "subcomponent_1".
```